# String java please decribe what is happening at the if statemtnt

Tags: java, if-statement

I have identified the line with which I am having trouble with a `// Here` comment. I don't understand what is happening at the `if`-statement .

```
String input = "Hello World!";
String temp = "";
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
    if (i != input.length() && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {   // Here
        temp = input.charAt(i) + temp;
    } else {
        result = temp + " " + result;
        temp = "";
    }
}

System.out.println("the result is: " + result);
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: What is confusing to you?

Comment: are you trying to reverse the string with spaces added in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is the counter.
 input.length() means the length of the string in your case (12).
 i++ increment by 1 at the end of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
```

i != input.length() this will check if i is not equal to the length of the string.
 input.charAt(i) != ' ' this will return the char at the current position let say.
 i = 0 that would return "H" because it is found at charAt(0).
 this if checks if i is not equal to the length of the string and the current character is not empty (not a whitespace).

```
if (i != input.length() && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
```

if not whitespace and counter is not bigger than the length do this

```
temp = input.charAt(i) + temp;
    } else {
```

if whitespace do this

```
result = temp + " " + result;
        temp = "";
    }
}

System.out.println("the result is: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i != input.length() && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
```

Equals to normal speak language

> if the value of variable 'i' is not the same as the length of the variable 'input' and the character at location 'i' in the variable 'input' is not a space.

Basically it checks if you have traven't traversed for the length of `input` and the current character is not a space.

Comment: This `if the value of variable 'i' is not the same as the length of the variable 'input'` is more like, `if the character position we are looking isn't after the end of the string and it isn't a space`

Comment: No, that's not correct. Nowhere does it check if it's 'after' the end of the string, it just checks if it's not the end.

Comment: My bad I read `!=` as `<`, I actually don't understand why someone would write code as they have, is it a broken `reverser()` + `trim()`?

Comment: If he doesn't do that, it will not reverse the last word (he's reversing them individually). That's why he has a check to see if it's either the end of the sentence or a space. If it is, he appends it to the result. If it isn't, he constructors the `temp` variable, which holds the reversed word.

Comment: You can also bypass this by removing `i != input.length() &&`, changing the condition to `i < input.length()` and adding a space at the end of the `input` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is checking if the length of the input is not the same as i, and the input character is not a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i != input.length() && input.charAt(i) != ' ')
```

Says two things must be true and is evaluated with a shortcircut.  First it checks if `i` is NOT equal to the length of the input. (`i != input.length()`)  IF and ONLY IF the first section is true will the second be evaluated.  The is the nature of a shortcircut (the  `&&` operator) evaluation.  The second section says the character at index `i` is not a space character. (`input.charAt(i) != ' '`)  If BOTH of these are true, then the expression is evaluated as true and the 'then' is executed.  If the first is false (shortcircuted), or the first is true and second is true then the else is executed.